# AIX - Memory space error when running script

Tags: linux, unix, shell, aix

I run the following:

```
for i in `ls -ld /u03/sss/| awk '{print $9}'`
do
echo $i
for j in  `find $i -name "*.gz" | grep $send_sysdate`
do
  count=`gunzip -c $j | wc -l`
  sum5=`expr $sum5 + $count`
done
#echo $sum5
echo "Transaction count for Socal Server Last month is $sum5 \n">> /tmp/count.txt
done
```

After the above runs for a while I receive:

```
./Transaction_count_prashantN.sh[33]: no space
./Transaction_count_prashantN.sh[33]: no space
./Transaction_count_prashantN.sh[33]: no space
./TranMemory fault
```

Comment: have you check if `/tmp` is full ? this might be reported by `errpt`.

Comment: Try to find which is the command that cause the error... maybe in `/u03/sss/` there are million of directories, or million of `gz` files in one of that, or million of files inside a `gz` file.  BTW you are appending  to `/tmp/count.txt` something related to the whole last month one time for each value of `$i`. If you want to add only the total you should put the last done before the echo line.